# How to flip a rotated rectangle in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, rotation, rotational-matrices

I want to flip back a rotated rectangle coming from an already flipped matrix, and do some math on it and get a new rectangle (not rotated). Just changing the x, y coordinates doesn't help, since the calculated rectangle will result in the opposite direction. For example, if I get the starting point of my new rectangle, it will expand towards the direction of the flipped input matrix, which is just the opposite direction of my resulted rectangle. The `cv::flip` function does not accept the rotatedRect as an input. So I have to ask for some help here.

Comment: Can you draw an example?

Comment: every rotated rect has vertices, angle and size properties for you to use. you can transform the corners (vertices) using these properties